# RecyclerView's size doesn't change after setting adapter

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

In a fragment, I set layout manager on a `RecyclerView` in `onActivityCreated`:-

```
galleryRecView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
```

Then I execute an `AsyncTask`, which downloads the data to be set in the RecyclerView.

Now I set the adapter on my RecyclerView:-

```
public void onPhotosURLsReceived(boolean success) {
    if (success && isAdded())
        galleryRecView.setAdapter(new GalleryAdapter(getActivity(), Constants.photosList));
}
```

**The problem**:-

The `RecyclerView`'s `layout_height` is set to `wrap_content`. So in the starting, when there is no adapter set on the RecyclerView, it takes a height of 0dp. When I set the adapter after the AsyncTask is over, it still remains at 0dp and nothing can be seen. This was never a problem with `ListView`.

**Note**:-

After I get this list working, I am planning to convert it to a non-scroll RecyclerView to use inside a `scrollView` and `swipeLayout` by extending `RecyclerView` and overriding `onMeasure` like this:-

```
public class NonScrollRecyclerView extends RecyclerView {

public NonScrollRecyclerView(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public NonScrollRecyclerView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public NonScrollRecyclerView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
}

 /*
 *  Non-scroll listview to use with SwipeRefreshLayout and scrollview
 */

@Override
public void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    int heightMeasureSpec_custom = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(
            Integer.MAX_VALUE >> 2, MeasureSpec.AT_MOST);
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec_custom);
    ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = getLayoutParams();
    params.height = getMeasuredHeight();
}
}
```

Comment: Try to call `galleryRecView.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();` after `galleryRecView.setAdapter(new GalleryAdapter(getActivity(), Constants.photosList));`. It's used to notify the registered observers that the data set has changed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out that `RecyclerView` inside a `ScrollView` was a problem.

I removed the ScrollView and put the content which was outside the RecyclerView, inside the RecyclerView as another view type by overriding `getItemViewType(int position)`.

This not only solved the problem, it also got rid of the need for a non-scroll RecyclerView. A non-scroll RecyclerView would not recycle views and the purpose of it would be defeated.